# Will Alistair agree to marry Anora even if he is not hardened?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I am trying to get Alistair and Anora to marry each other and let Loghain live at the landsmeet. So before the landsmeet began, I talked to Alistair and he agreed to marry Anora. Anora likewise agreed to marry Alistair.

However, when push comes to shove, he backs out after I say that I want to induct Loghain into the Gray Wardens, no matter what I do.

The trouble is, I don't remember if I hardened him or not (I played this game a few years ago and stopped playing when my system broke until recently).

So the question is, will he AGREE  to marry in the first place if he's not hardened (going through with the marriage is a separate issue)? All the guides I've seen mention that he must be hardened to get the ending, but they don't mention this question.

Comment: 'Hardened' is such an unfortunate term in this context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alistair will **agree** to marry Anora if you talk to them about it. It is independant of whether Alistair is hardened or not.

However, if you let Loghain live and Alistair is **not** hardened, he will retract and refuse to marry Anora.

The only way to let Loghain live **and** have Alistair marry Anora is to harden him.

To harden Alistair :

1. After visiting his sister, you have to choose the dialogue option "People are out for themselves."
2. Get his approval to Friendly or Adore (76+).
3. Once both of these requirements are met, the next time you visit camp and talk to him, he will tell you that, after what happened with his sister, he thinks you are right, and he should look more after himself. Selecting any dialogue option outside of "No, don't do that !" will harden him.

Answer (score 1):

If you induct Loghain into Grey Wardens then Alistar leave your party and there is no other solution. You have to kill Loghain to get Alistar to marry Anora. Also you must give the final blow to Loghain because if Alistar kills her father then she backs out.

Answer (score 1):

Alistar will agree regardless of whether he is hardened or not, his being hardened in this instance will only affect the epilogue text related to him